# Title and Meta Description not found by SEO checking websites

Tags: meta-tags, title, meta-description

I have a website and I'm trying to improve it's SEO ranking. I checked on several SEO checking websites and all of them say  the Title and Meta Description are not found. I'm sure there are there:

[image]
What could be causing the tools to report that they are missing?

Comment: What platform is your site running on? Is it a popular CMS or a proprietary one, or something else?

Comment: "meta title" or "title"? The "SEO checking website" might be fooled by the conditional comment that immediately precedes the meta description element, thinking that it is commented out. (?) But the meta description plays no part in "SEO ranking" anyway.

Comment: @HenryVisotski is the "platform" relevant?

Comment: @MrWhite It is, specifically if the CMS is not a popular one but a proprietary solution. For example, I worked for a company whose whole CMS was cobbled together by one programmer. It worked, but had quirks: the system wouldn't recognize or generate any meta tags properly unless you specifically whitelisted them on the backend. So if we're talking about an obscure platform, something like that could be the culprit.

Comment: Which SEO checking websites did you use?    Unfortunately a large number of them are broken or give very poor SEO advice.    Because you used multiple of them, it may be a problem with your site, but it still could be a problem with the tools

Comment: Have you tested your site with private browsing and with command line tools such as `wget` and `curl`?  It could be that your site is configured to output the meta data only to some user agents, or only to logged in users.

Comment: What is your website?   We don't really have any way of investigating this further without knowing what your site is.

Comment: If you do a Fetch as Google using Search Console, do you see what you expect? If so, then who cares what SEO site fails? If not, then it would be good to see this problem live via your domain name. Cheers!!